# Can't delete folder in android 11 form internal storage even after allowing MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Tags: android, android-11

I can not be able to delete folders in internal storage even after allowing "MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" permission.

```
File file = new File("/storage/emulated/0/T4");
file.delete();
```

"file.delete();" is not working but code is not crashing and folder is still exist in android 11 device.

Thanks in advance

Comment: if(!file.delete()) return;

Comment: still not working

Comment: Of course not. But you should have it in your code and also display a Toast to inform the user.

Comment: What is in that folder?

Comment: nothing is in the folder

Comment: You should have told that at the start of your post. We have to ask all. if (!file.exists()) return;

Comment: if ( !file.canWrite()) return;  Display always a Toast if you return. We wait for you updating your code here.

Answer (score 0):

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

MainActivity:

```
delete_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {

                    if (Environment.isExternalStorageManager()){

                     File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/T4");
                     boolean success =  deleteFolder(dir);

                     // here you can check whether the folder has been deleted or not

                        if (success){
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Delete succeeded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Delete failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }else {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
                        Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package",getPackageName(),null);
                        intent.setData(uri);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }

                }else {

                    // other SDK version

          }

     }
```

Delete method

```
  private boolean deleteFolder(File dir) {
        File[] files = dir.listFiles();
        if (files != null) {
            for (File file : files) {
                deleteFolder(file);
            }
        }
        return dir.delete();
    }
```

Comment: i tried as you said but not working

Comment: @BradPitt I tested the code in my project and it works fine . check logcat

Comment: i have removed hard coded value but still its not getting deleted

Comment: @BradPitt It didn't work for you because there are other files inside the folder. I updated the code to delete the folder and its contents

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete folders which contain files.

Comment: why can't we delete? can you give me some example or any document

Comment: What did you do more to get ' all files access' than just that permission in manifest? You could better tell what you all did.